# Powerbuilder files missing .pbw file

Tags: powerbuilder

I received a bunch of .pbl files and asked to install the app. I have never worked with Powerbuilder before but, aren't you supposed to also have a Workspace file included? Well, I am told this is all I have.

When I try opening the files on pb12.5 I get asked immediately for the database connection but because I can't open the files I don't see what DB connection settings I should put in there to make it work.

How can I open pw files when there is no workspace defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new Workspace and Target, and add the PBLs to the target.  If you don't know  where the application object is to start, the inheritance setup *et cetera* you might have to adjust things a bit to get it to compile properly.

Better to get the as-designed PBW & PBT if you can.  Are the PBLs perhaps from an older version of PB before Workspaces were in use?

Comment: Thanks. Well, the deal is, another developer had the app but left only these files so I've been asked to make it work with what they have. Will try your suggestion. Thanks again.

Comment: DaveE, Thanks, I did exactly what you told me and it worked. I tried voting but it seems I don't have the reputation needed for that. Thanks again!

Comment: Actually, you'll find you *don't* need to know where the application object is, what the inheritance hierarchy is, etc... to set up a library list for a target path. What is more important is whether or not there are duplicate objects (same name, same type, different PBLs) in this list. When there are duplicates, the one found first is picked. If this is the case and you have a PBL sequence so that a different object is selected, you may have different behaviour. If there are no duplicates, sequence won't matter.